# Removing HTML canvas alpha channel

Tags: optimization, html, canvas

I have a very large html canvas element covering a solid background. I would assume that a lot of cpu could be saved when scrolling/panning if the browser did not blend the canvas to elements behind it (in this case, a solid color).

Is it possible to remove the canvas alpha channel? Should this be left up to browsers to detect and optimize for? Or would speed gains be insignificant?

Answer (score 5):

MDN [suggests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Optimizing_canvas#Turn_off_transparency) setting the alpha option in the canvas context:

> If your application uses canvas and doesn’t need a transparent backdrop, set the `alpha` option to `false` when creating a drawing context with `HTMLCanvasElement.getContext()`. This information can be used internally by the browser to optimize rendering.

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d', { alpha: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, just put a rectangle without alpha :)

```
var context = document.getElementById("id of your canvas").getContext("2d");

context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)"; // (red, green, blue, alpha from 0 to 255);

// or just

context.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)"; // without alpha
context.fillRect(0, 0, your_canvas_width, your_canvas_height);
```